# using pinned file in windows console application

Tags: c#, windows-console

I'm creating a windows console application to easily execute batch files I often use, and thought it would be easy to pin the application to my taskbar and pin the batch files on the icon. My question is how does the application know with what file it is called, does it get put in the main arguments for example?

Comment: yes, it would be in the arguments which get passed to the main point of entry in the application (Main method)

Comment: Do you know why I get a prompt asking me with what program to open bat files as soon as I use the pinned files?

Comment: I see what you mean. you want to associate a particular file extension with your program? you need to register that with Windows itself.

Comment: No, not exactly, because when I call the program with a batch file as parameter from my CMD, it works fine, but when I right-click the icon in my taskbar and select a batch file I pinned to it it gives me that prompt